# Não retorna a tabela

Tags: php, html

tenho a página **consumo.php** onde tenho o **menu:**

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Registos</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#produto_44">Diário Alimentação</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#produto_45">Diário Alimentação Centro Dia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#produto_46">Consultar Registo Diário Alimentação</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#produto_47">Consultar Registo Diário Alimentação Concluídas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#produto_48">Diário Alimentação Reforço AAD</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#produto_49">Consultar Diário Alimentação Reforço</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#produto_50">Resguardos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#produto_51">Mapa Resumo Resguardos</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="hide-section" id="produto_46"> 

</section>

</body> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#produto_46").load("./produto_46");

$(".sub-menu li a").click(function(){ 
$("section[id^='produto_']").addClass("hide-section"); 
var id = $(this).attr("href"); 
$(id).removeClass("hide-section"); 
}); 

var h = window.location.hash; 
if(h) $(".sub-menu li a[href='"+h+"']").trigger("click"); 

 });
</script>
```

Depois tenho a página produto_46 onde tenho o formulário para colocar o período de tempo:

```
 <?php
    /*
    Template Name: produto_46
    */ 

    include ('./consulta_1');

    ?>

    <form class="shadowbox6" class="form-validate" id="feedback_form16">
    <fieldset class="grupo">
     <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
     <tr>
       <td>
        <strong><label for="Insira data de inicio:">Insira data de inicio:</label></strong>
        <input type="Date" name="inicio" placeholder="PESQUISAR" style="width:150px" required="" size="120">
        </td>
       <td>
        <strong><label for="Insira data de fim:">Insira data de fim:</label></strong>
        <input type="Date" name="fim" placeholder="PESQUISAR" style="width:150px" required="" size="120">
        </td>
    </tr>
     </table>
    </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Consultar</button>
    </form>
```

Depois tenho a página consulta_1 onde tenho a php para retornar a tabela:

```
FROM centrodb.RegistoDiario

WHERE Estado IS NULL AND DataRegisto >= '$inicio' AND DataRegisto <= '$fim'";

$result_cursos1 = "SELECT Id,
       DataRegisto,
       Dia,
       TipoRefeicao,
       Refeicao,
       Hora,
       Motivo,
       Sugestao,
       Colaborador,
       Tratamento,
       Estado

FROM centrodb.RegistoDiarioDia

WHERE Estado IS NULL AND DataRegisto >= '$inicio' AND DataRegisto <= '$fim'";


$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$resultado_cursos1 = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos1);

$tabela1 .= '<div id="tabela19" style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela1 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .='<thead>';

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="80">Nº Registo</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="100">Data</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Dia</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Tipo de Refeição</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Refeicao</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Hora da Refeição</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="160">Motivo do incumprimento</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="240">Sugestões / Observações</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="110">Colaborador</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="160">Tratamento</th>';

$tabela1 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Concluído</th>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela1 .='<tbody>';

$tabela2 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

$tabela2 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela2 .= '<tr>';

$tabela2 .='<thead>';

$tabela2 .= '<tr>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="80">Nº Registo</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="100">Data</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Dia</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Tipo de Refeição</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Refeicao</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Hora da Refeição</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="160">Motivo do incumprimento</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="240">Sugestões / Observações</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="110">Colaborador</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="160">Tratamento</th>';

$tabela2 .= '<th WIDTH="90">Concluído</th>';

$tabela2 .= '</tr>';

$tabela2 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela2 .='<tbody>';

    while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Dia'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['TipoRefeicao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Refeicao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Hora'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Motivo'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Sugestao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Colaborador'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="text" name= "Tratamento['.$rows_cursos['Id'].']" id= "Tratamento" value="'.$rows_cursos['Tratamento'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Id[]" value="'.$rows_cursos['Id'].'"></td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>'; 

while($rows_cursos1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos1)) {

$tabela2 .= '<tr>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['Id'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['Dia'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['TipoRefeicao'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['Refeicao'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['Hora'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['Motivo'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['Sugestao'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos1['Colaborador'].'</td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td> <input type="text" name= "Tratamento['.$rows_cursos1['Id'].']" id= "Tratamento" value="'.$rows_cursos1['Tratamento'].'"></td>';

$tabela2 .= '<td> <input type="checkbox" name= "Id[]" value="'.$rows_cursos1['Id'].'"></td>';

$tabela2 .= '</tr>'; 
}}}
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

$tabela1 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela1 .= '</table>';

$tabela1 .= '</div>';

$tabela2 .= '</tr>';

$tabela2 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela2 .= '</table>';

$tabela2 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela1;

?>
</br>
</br>
<form class="shadowbox3" class="form-validate" action="" method="post"> 
    <div class="campo">
         <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Consultar Registo Diário Alimentação Centro de Dia</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br>
            </fieldset>
    </div>  
</form>

<?php 

echo $tabela2; 

?>
```

Até à parte onde coloco o período de tempo, funciona tudo bem, mas quando faço consultar esse período de tempo não retorna nada. Eu acho que o problema está na página onde tenho o php, consulta_1.php, mas ainda não consegui encontrar o problema. A consola não me retorna erro nenhum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após vários esclarecimentos no **[chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79593/discussion-between-dvd-and-sdkamda2323)**, ficou resolvido com a utilização de Ajax:

```
$("#feedback_form16").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "./consulta_1",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data) {
         $('#produto_46').html(data);
       }
   });
});
```

Faz uma consulta a página `./consulta_1` e enviar o retorno para a `div #produto_46`.

Answer (score 0):

Seu include está sem a extensão do arquivo php. Tente inserir a extensão e testar novamente.

Comment: Não é esse o problema, porque utilizo o wordpress e no wordpress é dessa forma que chamo a página e não consulta_1.php, porque se fizer desta forma diz que a página não existe, erro 404

Comment: Certo. Imprime a consulta da página e executa no banco para ver se vem resultados. Pode ser que o formato da sua data esteja diferente do padrão que o banco aceita yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: se imprimir a página onde ttenho a consulta retorna os dados da consulta na tabela.

Comment: Tenta forçar a mostrar os erros no início do arquivo.                          ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Não retorna erros, eu penso que o problema estará aqui logo no inicio `if((isset($_POST['inicio'])) && (isset($_POST['fim'])) && (!empty($_POST['inicio'])) && (!empty($_POST['fim']))){$inicio=$_POST['inicio']; $fim=$_POST['fim'];`, ou está correto

Comment: Verifica os valores de post. Você pode fazer isso com var_dump($_POST). É para aparecer os valores quando você clicar em consultar. Verifica também se não tem mais de uma vez em sua página os names inicio e fim, pois caso tenha não vai funcionar.

Comment: podemos falar no chat?

Comment: Acredito que não tenho privilégio ainda para chamar no chat. Se você conseguir me chamar.